# How do I export tables in nuxt.js

Tags: nuxt.js

I want to download the table data with a click of a button, but I don't know how to do that in nuxt.js. The table data is pulled from a local JSON file and then looped through the table

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(value,index) in list.product.table" :key="index">
        <td v-for="(v,j) in value" :key="j">{{v}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You should probably download the JSON file when you click on the button.

Answer (score 0):

The thread title is kind of wrong, You've meant 'How do I import data tables into table in nuxt.js'? :)

You can easily attach download action of the local JSON file to btn.click event. The data can be imported just when the btn is clicked by using `await import('...')`.

It's worth to attach computed properties and some `v-if="..."` to check availability of the data.

```js
<template>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <div style="width: 100%">
            <button @click="downloadJSONData">Download table data</button>
        </div>
        <table v-if="isDataAvailable" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <tbody>
                <tr
                    v-for="(itemRow, rowIndex) in tableData"
                    :key="`row-${rowIndex}`"
                >
                    <td
                        v-for="(columnItem, columnIndex) in itemRow"
                        :key="`row-${columnIndex}`"
                    >
                        {{ columnItem }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div v-else-if="isLoading" style="width: 100%">
            <strong>Loading table data ...</strong>
        </div>
        <div v-else style="width: 100%">
            <strong>No data provided for the table</strong>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'DataTableComponent',
        data() {
            return {
                list: {},
                isLoading: false
            }
        },
        computed: {
            isDataAvailable() {
                return !!Object.keys(this.list).length
            },
            tableData() {
                return this.list?.product?.table || []
            }
        },
        methods: {
            async downloadJSONData() {
                this.isLoading = true
                this.list = await import('./data/productsList.json')
                this.isLoading = false
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```